# Support TrendNet TEW-643PI Wireless N network card

Tags: drivers, wireless

Has anyone been able to get a TrendNet TEW-643PI Wireless N card working under Ubuntu? If so, what drivers did you use and where did you find them?  I have this card and would really like to be able to use it in my computer.  I found drivers that may work but don't know how to get Ubuntu to recognize the drivers.  I have tried the Additional Drivers option but cannot seem to get Ubuntu to pick up the drivers.

Comment: Can you explain where you got the drivers from?

Comment: what does ifconfig say? is it recognized at all?

Comment: @ManoharBhattarai please use the edit summary to explain your edit, and the comments for clarifications to the Question :)

Answer (score 1):

These two posts on the *Ubuntu Forums* talk about your wireless card and possible solution. Maybe give it a try.

- [trendnet tew-643pi wireless card not working](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1031999)
- [Wireless pci card not working with encryption](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1025208)

Comment: It would be better to add some more details to your answer. At least just name the possible ways and give proper text to your link. naming like 1,2 is not fair.

Comment: Both links provide a solution about installing ndiswrapper to install the trendnet driver and disabling WEP and trying WPA for encryption.

Answer (score 0):

If you download ndisgtk, there is a way to get it to work. Using the driver cd that came with the network card, navigate to Drivers/Windows XP/x86 on the cd and drag the .inf file to ndisgtk. It will ask to confirm the location, so hit 'Install.' After a few seconds, you should get some kind of wireless connection.

To download ndisgtk, run this from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ndisgtk
```