# Wireless network card not working (Trendnet TEW-643pi)

Tags: 10.10, wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Support TrendNet TEW-643PI Wireless N network card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24187/support-trendnet-tew-643pi-wireless-n-network-card)

I've unstalled Ubuntu, but I can't connect to my wireless network.

I have a Trendnet TEW-643pi card, and many post say it will not work. Should I connect my ethernet and try to update the drivers?